# Where can I find old versions of the JDK and JRE?

Tags: sun, java

To test compatibility, I need to find old versions of the JRE and JDK. Where can I find download links to these files?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here you can find all sorts of old download links. JDK, JRE, and even different libraries!

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Comment: now bound to registration?

Comment: And signing up does not work, "Failure of server APACHE bridge", hilarious...

Comment: oracle now requires you to register which is annoying.  https://jdk.java.net/archive/ doesn't have as quite as many, but may be good enough

Answer (score 8):

found a [bundleid table](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/plugins/tool-installer/trunk/jre-table.txt) for jre. you put the bundleid which is the first row (the number) into the link `http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=######` (replace ###### with number)

```
43686=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom19-latest.msi?e=1295448769025&h=f60d71a4e30531bc3ef8bd574845430e
43687=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom20-latest.msi?e=1295448773933&h=da2f70b52b1967022bca3866a9bba418
43688=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom21-b06.msi?e=1295448778931&h=1a5693bcdd9d62f98aea54ff32f768de
43689=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom21-latest.msi?e=1295448783929&h=9d52efd24df9fd671aec61f93c0fd52d
43690=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom22-latest.msi?e=1295448789107&h=c0f7b17899ec3e7bffbd4e3b39104af9
43691=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-s-l.msi?e=1295448794103&h=75fee68842249047aaf8f235828bfc4c
43692=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-s.msi?e=1295448798929&h=b52cf71631b779aed3349a974268a39a
43693=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1295448803928&h=92f83bc958d25c5316df3dc337a6879b
43694=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-i586.bin?e=1295448808929&h=4df3bdf93da6de200a2263316fb39f1b
43695=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-ia64-rpm.bin?e=1295448814122&h=759c0909b97af06281cb5af74a4dc8e9
43696=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-ia64.bin?e=1295448595783&h=ddfd88d6927239fd88fe4f67dba109b7
43697=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-x64-rpm.bin?e=1295448600008&h=bef313be6109d7b2f847b0025a5097b3
43698=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-linux-x64.bin?e=1295448604993&h=5f63245f04ec2ac7056d5b5037e66500
43699=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-solaris-i586.sh?e=1295448609990&h=d446a52c1ea7822fd3944dfd7ec8477f
43700=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-solaris-sparc.sh?e=1295448615173&h=dd483ceceb7950ab489df7fdf7e2601a
43701=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-solaris-sparcv9.sh?e=1295448619990&h=ccd98a59361abdd5d54042f6479734f6
43702=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-solaris-x64.sh?e=1295448625171&h=3c2a449b47d3728b5605a4083bb035a2
43703=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-i586-s.exe?e=1295448629988&h=e710a4004c153f76f031d59c1d16d36c
43704=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-i586.exe?e=1295448634986&h=88c010d78cfac16a886fa8e8b2c8ee68
43705=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-ia64.exe?e=1295448640174&h=dfef76b20cbeca9bf37d3a12ff0ebdeb
43706=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-x64.exe?e=1295448495998&h=1d83fc770687a8b2c51c3540eb25b35a
43707=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/JavaSetup6u23-rv.exe?e=1295448500041&h=5ba363444efdf52bf785a908408ea917
43708=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/JavaSetup6u23-sprev.exe?e=1295448505024&h=659b30ba7303f1a78ce847ac21ca3136
43709=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/JavaSetup6u23.exe?e=1295448510044&h=d748352206c7c07e52a3a4c4933f7ad2
43710=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/chromeinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010-rv.exe?e=1295448515233&h=1e3c923fb3b0a967601ee9d249247e4e
43711=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/chromeinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010.exe?e=1295448520065&h=b8bb9e208356730a9cee35f48af65dd2
43712=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/chromeinstall-6u23.exe?e=1295448525207&h=5bf4bafd491d7332e29e0e92c58e25c7
43713=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/chromeinstall-rv.exe?e=1295448530224&h=f83b86a2cd5f547c088c6eaf0f4cff33
43714=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/chromeinstall.exe?e=1295448535217&h=a3641dffcb37577653fea5e636ddbdcb
43715=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jinstall-6u23-windows-i586-rv.cab?e=1295448540024&h=41cb3b9c176f28a899b4aefdf616e230
43716=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jinstall-6u23-windows-i586.cab?e=1295448404416&h=a734dc98f9ee1c5cfdbeb5cdca82b8f9
43717=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-i586-iftw-k.exe?e=1295448409066&h=7c2ed84b0a237216c6ee754ce7917ed5
43718=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-i586-iftw-rv.exe?e=1295448414352&h=d21571fc193aed17260de9ff9755cabf
43719=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre-6u23-windows-i586-iftw.exe?e=1295448419243&h=d51a794f4e328e81fd11897ec8c018dd
43720=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jxpiinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010-rv.exe?e=1295448424238&h=3bd54aec44af6516cfb17adbc3406e45
43721=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jxpiinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010.exe?e=1295448429065&h=ef1de5a641d6ff04eccf3e3b6348e539
43722=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jxpiinstall-rv.exe?e=1295448434229&h=f397acbc88f3d30ee0d43cb8faf2210f
43723=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jxpiinstall.exe?e=1295448440065&h=8b3d1534f0f0eb2d067efeed7547063a
43724=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/xpiinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010-rv.exe?e=1295448445054&h=e05a059a5373d6c9f1ef1405eddc9dd6
43725=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/xpiinstall-6u23-fcs-bin-b04-windows-i586-05_nov_2010.exe?e=1295448450062&h=1111d58ad8ecbaf23a9f2c7b1af0a410
43726=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/xpiinstall-rv.exe?e=1295448323156&h=df410ef2ffb28e2869fd7fee39200b79
43727=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/xpiinstall.exe?e=1295448328084&h=7e780c55c20755d2b51a653eb3c68d61
43728=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_de.jpg?e=1295448333266&h=a1f84e9ce36ca3ecccc54015c70f1d42
43729=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_en.jpg?e=1295448338265&h=a5c60d65b9087b3333ac363d2913b9a3
43730=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_es.jpg?e=1295448345087&h=35bfd5f77e64937b085d59d13071cbe9
43731=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_fr.jpg?e=1295448350265&h=c2a5e89e3c96892aad4225bbf4fe888d
43732=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_it.jpg?e=1295448355070&h=7392a9c23cc4921726725e0f695d5846
43733=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_ja.jpg?e=1295448360106&h=7f23c1bb75b85a6dccefa7d6fdaecd11
43734=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_ko.jpg?e=1295448365076&h=e530eb7b171e45e475062ad6e3e5e6e6
43735=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_pt_BR.jpg?e=1295448370073&h=31a9554be1b66f851c1f86dca77a03e1
43736=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_sv.jpg?e=1295448256654&h=715a62c12aad83293afcab9fab647fc0
43737=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_zh.jpg?e=1295448261302&h=a447465bde987df99abde44747ec7547
43738=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/OpenOffice_banner_zh_TW.jpg?e=1295448266375&h=f7c4b1b485a01216dd743202048a3515
43739=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1.6.0_23-c-k.msi?e=1295448271312&h=732cca5d5b1952675455023fe6987e71
43740=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1028.MST?e=1295448276366&h=111201773406528cb5eb6bff7acc0fbc
43741=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1031.MST?e=1295448281283&h=4f554ae51643fb660664ebdabe2fbe2f
43742=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1034.MST?e=1295448286275&h=324158d04848ff30d730bb02ba208853
43743=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1036.MST?e=1295448291304&h=566563417ce21dc5c2b36a1483905749
43744=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1040.MST?e=1295448296297&h=798c45af077a00fd0b71cc285d934b8a
43745=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1041.MST?e=1295448301099&h=07567c9fcd69802f7953b8affcded013
43746=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1042.MST?e=1295448156308&h=935c4c7a76a748dacd43ca4a6f214492
43747=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1046.MST?e=1295448161167&h=03e825ccc5a9b6ac29285e5d9ffeacc8
43748=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre1053.MST?e=1295448166416&h=4eea46ff8337f9cc2b65c4be392cca9c
43749=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/jre/jre2052.MST?e=1295448171359&h=da95acec4430613101c07429cdd0d26e
43750=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/charsets.zip?e=1295448176157&h=e927399d12c577fe5c16942d3e420c26
43751=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/client_jvm.zip?e=1295448181303&h=99c47a659bec9dadca674d0290eb6b45
43752=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/cmm.zip?e=1295448186157&h=f0dfa812ef9f9d4c1fac76b2bec818c8
43753=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/cmm_rare.zip?e=1295448191138&h=f692aa8f74e7befcd2cbf1ecbf683e6b
43754=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_oracle_net.zip?e=1295448196142&h=e80abb5568df31b09e5864f588cae4cf
43755=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_awt.zip?e=1295448201316&h=ef1e07c911d3d84752a6f86e19f84b00
43756=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_java_swing.zip?e=1295448076030&h=26d02992636d6559827ae9b4df42ec1a
43757=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_java_swing_plaf_nimbus.zip?e=1295448081366&h=aaf0758a6704d0fd642e0df0a85c49fd
43758=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_java_util_jar_pack.zip?e=1295448086180&h=057bc7f4d0a5ef45c1e5421d8b865ab4
43759=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_jndi.zip?e=1295448091338&h=79459d68f678a8d45243a136de02c742
43760=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_org_apache_bcel_internal.zip?e=1295448096338&h=ec0f4288a392606732fa384a8742565c
43761=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_org_apache_regexp_internal.zip?e=1295448101157&h=3ae0c8aca11320d2238ef41e7050f625
43762=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_org_apache_xalan_internal.zip?e=1295448106349&h=a2626244fab0e3909dfffa01eb350ae5
43763=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_org_apache_xml_internal.zip?e=1295448111165&h=814caceb9f2d6be6fb5abf24700c3027
43764=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_org_apache_xpath_internal.zip?e=1295448116148&h=c6a5a53f15fa0500d43f5f52e7daf4f5
43765=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_security.zip?e=1295448121337&h=71c1907965f5a1e3ebabf625c161d532
43766=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_servicetag.zip?e=1295447981760&h=754550f44959c1bbbcfa61620854ba28
43767=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_servicetag_resources.zip?e=1295447986180&h=1c4a3b8a5dde991595a92d3cac7e5ce9
43768=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/com_sun_xml.zip?e=1295447991176&h=6f73935749720f7fe3fe69b868edcd25
43769=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/db.zip?e=1295447996192&h=36027d4737138698f5382136958a691b
43770=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/dcpr.zip?e=1295448001203&h=41a7e9a8ba898521c18018ab8b652d2c
43771=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/deploy.zip?e=1295448006179&h=73ccb957fe96fb5c61a0d7e1b4d1ec4c
43772=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/extra_dlls.zip?e=1295448011350&h=d47c8cd9da10cc31c3f8d7db0deb8523
43773=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/extra_exes.zip?e=1295448016376&h=126d46222b629c13a17b996127045609
43774=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/extras.zip?e=1295448021342&h=45afc4688e5163defa8f5856537c2221
43775=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/extras_plugin.zip?e=1295448026353&h=47f6f9657ec3244115756c5f4a0455b0
43776=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/font_lucidasansregular.zip?e=1295447894434&h=910466a8631728acca13d5917900e40b
43777=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/fonts.zip?e=1295447899434&h=7151f9aa3faf65d9aa74525ca68a0592
43778=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/index.html?e=1295447904400&h=39229a80bf1a9857526fb1524e0b6f6d
43779=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/indicim.zip?e=1295447909210&h=a7b39ca02a0a5e4d021ea65f7e9552f9
43780=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_2d.zip?e=1295447914210&h=db4310b0f5c4976ba0d68aee4841be9c
43781=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_applet.zip?e=1295447919202&h=894cf6f93055c5b779dfd56fb5dc22d3
43782=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_awt.zip?e=1295447924200&h=2cd4406e947001a0a3e0ea08119894af
43783=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_awt_core.zip?e=1295447929381&h=aa8853f2788a857cc3c15ee532790646
43784=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_awt_services.zip?e=1295447934379&h=d7ede13cb52d29525cfa8bfd09684e6e
43785=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_beans.zip?e=1295447941378&h=bef3668d6fb659e5a1aea5c6084975fa
43786=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_beans_core.zip?e=1295447669459&h=b0204f1d566f6d41fa7abe397f01e832
43787=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_geom.zip?e=1295447674458&h=386cb7ec12c248776570b5896feeaaf9
43788=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_image.zip?e=1295447679283&h=9efda9e493d492cdef2a9f0a03d7c027
43789=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_rmi.zip?e=1295447684432&h=c84ef3845115f6f2e72792783ae706b3
43790=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_security.zip?e=1295447689250&h=efabce0020ac35be1a485927407183c8
43791=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/java_security_core.zip?e=1295447694439&h=65866898906538d7c8df8a70ae18b34d
43792=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_imageio.zip?e=1295447699438&h=e0edd37f5d5ed5cb359f5192f1e1b143
43793=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_lang.zip?e=1295447704452&h=96918853cd6e98050c000410eba9bed9
43794=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_management.zip?e=1295447709420&h=00ce37e90f7465381de80c380dd39fcf
43795=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_naming.zip?e=1295447714262&h=3ad477bf310cc635f9324c44eb6fd721
43796=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_print.zip?e=1295447243150&h=067a8bfcfe15fb88d65e13126fa68c9e
43797=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_script.zip?e=1295447247567&h=cadd0d78d0f8a60395c5e36c2eec571a
43798=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_security.zip?e=1295447252377&h=32388bdedb063c4fd9e247ca58a1f516
43799=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_sound.zip?e=1295447257550&h=272fec3b48d389bc702d6538b349797e
43800=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing.zip?e=1295447262547&h=6d585997a72237defaf10c7855194a0f
43801=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_core.zip?e=1295447267679&h=1e6be2689ab67a48925819abaa8b6549
43802=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_extracomponents.zip?e=1295447272542&h=2439446b3b88fa9405c84fb389fcb296
43803=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_min.zip?e=1295447277371&h=efff9464d4d93f0870072c250ced1d01
43804=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_plaf_metal.zip?e=1295447282553&h=88dcdaef106c89c2a868b238977def99
43805=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_plaf_motif.zip?e=1295447287547&h=ad96266ed7c69569d04d9b6d89f8e4db
43806=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_plaf_synth.zip?e=1295445931860&h=ae21d4cd3f3f0926e77e8764b04608bb
43807=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_plaf_windows.zip?e=1295445936055&h=33e2da91a37db5ed69f6bb2bb367bed7
43808=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_table.zip?e=1295445940251&h=96e589e8d0c164cf6f1b3f827188d04e
43809=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_text.zip?e=1295445944612&h=8fb66c58ca16a406957ecc2bc334f42c
43810=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_text_html.zip?e=1295445948806&h=869533a84f9b2f53c5b734fa541758fe
43811=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_text_rtf.zip?e=1295445952833&h=b4b991cf9a1d691664fa108a56884fb4
43812=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_swing_tree.zip?e=1295445957027&h=c994a386e2bdd4ee0395f57793169f6d
43813=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_ws.zip?e=1295445961398&h=0e3ce60c8a4fe6c7d3bb918d31735a55
43814=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_xml.zip?e=1295445965598&h=37a730eeb6b2d15352fef33879efdd60
43815=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_xml_core_dom.zip?e=1295445969631&h=7b380c943d2cca0cb781e5399835db02
43816=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_xml_core_sax.zip?e=1295445848657&h=80d88cb21b214e1903d85eed4ce05eed
43817=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_xml_w3c.zip?e=1295445852861&h=e6093b3da31d50008226f7ac8ee1c2f2
43818=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/javax_xml_xerces.zip?e=1295445857056&h=b6d85ddc52c13a4d8ec17f1b4cef946d
43819=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/jce.zip?e=1295445861763&h=ba80c13beb7caf1cd32e2a24d39a7e1f
43820=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/jpeg.zip?e=1295445865958&h=01fc2649b49ffffba1dbe6885bbd47a4
43821=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/jsse.zip?e=1295445870160&h=cc3b545939b3a43ff175ed6a664443be
43822=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/localedata.zip?e=1295445874356&h=641354d4fa90ab5ff74c05bd00321755
43823=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/misc.zip?e=1295445878718&h=fffe6c33f0432afdc7d494b281db47cc
43824=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/org_jcp_xml_dsig.zip?e=1295445882750&h=8e2862f2648ce90aae0e58cd058c1852
43825=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/org_omg_CORBA.zip?e=1295445886944&h=b94fd274360990226ad3279fd5bca64e
43826=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/plugin.zip?e=1295445670105&h=bf4d0fa6cfef6faaf1e7d99fabe13d55
43827=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/rare.zip?e=1295445674994&h=651cd95327f5586d509dc3c46a1c25aa
43828=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_de.zip?e=1295445679977&h=4a2765a78d3c72d581f41b7e57014a83
43829=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_es.zip?e=1295445684993&h=aededd4b02e3e01dd9e7bbd3e2d701eb
43830=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_fr.zip?e=1295445689980&h=99ef4deacaee1b393ce4b4c29fc550f8
43831=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_it.zip?e=1295445695000&h=01ba088cfbe2bf03b4f880bfcb0f774e
43832=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_ja.zip?e=1295445699986&h=5871f3b2af3e11837bde06bea2d8ac04
43833=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_ko.zip?e=1295445704977&h=c4c0aa3c310569ffa251e3e9fd27521a
43834=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_other.zip?e=1295445709974&h=d7704ca1246d19193b52b2df98ee52e7
43835=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_sv.zip?e=1295445714972&h=075dc5e85fce64140f4e1e17d4e1612b
43836=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/resources_zh.zip?e=1295445579447&h=e62b8048e67ab871511a571c2cd55d39
43837=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/soundbanks.zip?e=1295445583485&h=8ae9de36cc1700dc8109d094702b969c
43838=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_font.zip?e=1295445587873&h=704afe700d480f00832bf853e2a63580
43839=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_org_mozilla.zip?e=1295445593064&h=fe72d58a03f3dd82bb7eb2b194fb1323
43840=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_security.zip?e=1295445598035&h=8bd8c58fe0c011ac98db415db7fdae0f
43841=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_security_jgss.zip?e=1295445603035&h=1a2b638ea9b5c0c101a2c0e9f0bdc0ff
43842=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_security_krb5.zip?e=1295445607878&h=4591cddaddcfe08d0ca4344436531930
43843=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_security_x509.zip?e=1295445613036&h=cfe8d814fe9f3507c87d8e1b6ac75dc3
43844=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_swing.zip?e=1295445617841&h=12d63650c3d0a02ba53296a9d19bcb60
43845=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sun_text_resources.zip?e=1295445622831&h=7207c2b92fb68d1f1f02ee0a9d11a016
43846=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sunjce_provider.zip?e=1295445436514&h=bbd20fcb9230c67685f05c5a20430201
43847=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sunmscapi.zip?e=1295445440908&h=5e7f3397bbde5a85907f5081b496c367
43848=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/sunpkcs11.zip?e=1295445446067&h=9d1f50f8eb5e2dc39d3d5749a333edb6
43849=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/thaiim.zip?e=1295445450102&h=6ebed0d67f5dd0fc3a7adba0019a08b2
43850=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b04/kernel/tools.zip?e=1295445454308&h=16d77a6fe1bb9144d47004b4ccf0966a
43851=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-c-l.msi?e=1295445459021&h=73d740761644185c47f0795a49a897ad
43852=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-c.msi?e=1295445464017&h=43386379a05918f18e264a53a9761668
43853=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom10.msi?e=1295445468212&h=57549f3c0cb2ba0bb375b5638ef28e06
43854=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom11.msi?e=1295445472417&h=59274abe27bab9eed21760c55de889eb
43855=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom12.msi?e=1295445476621&h=30884255b3f933f1b2fc457cdd6e658a
43856=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom13.msi?e=1295445480800&h=6e677676fbe32a4ff13a8321f8036065
43857=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom14.msi?e=1295445356918&h=2c2c0100d750eb0fa416a326fb0f2662
43858=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom15.msi?e=1295445361276&h=5e12b3b6723cfee34410835ca015770b
43859=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom16.msi?e=1295445365473&h=1cef61feb861c47bbdd993dd291bd15e
43860=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom17.msi?e=1295445369939&h=e4847a5bbf09500394fa546ec84fa4dc
43861=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom18.msi?e=1295445374312&h=ac1fc3579a01df3d6b3cadce5aafa547
43862=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom19.msi?e=1295445379082&h=799ba5070519e46087c4382747ae4375
43863=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom20.msi?e=1295445383276&h=711e5ae314971b7f947ae2a3f30fb017
43864=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom21-b06.msi?e=1295445387469&h=8739639e804641bb75d5357c872b8bd5
43865=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom21.msi?e=1295445392059&h=0dc12a003420f58c940b4537bf801241
43866=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-pfrom22.msi?e=1295445271532&h=bbd0bfa3c448ee766b116c943f9ff9b5
43867=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-s-l.msi?e=1295445275072&h=a1f21102e6ed048a148e75c38c84fd29
43868=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre/jre1.6.0_23-s.msi?e=1295445278269&h=d2cdf495b847bb353642a5de78eceffa
43869=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/kernel/merged.zip?e=1295445281306&h=64ba2dbb66315deee0102c0b8d81046e
43870=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1295445284652&h=6233038564b859c5871ddb00849f131a
43871=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-i586.bin?e=1295445287835&h=b88361ceaad6eac12fda0743ac56400f
43872=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-ia64-rpm.bin?e=1295445290896&h=02dabc8ccb66045876eecb9fe726efc7
43873=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-ia64.bin?e=1295445294096&h=6a0ed2a89c49163347b319c40f31947d
43874=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-x64-rpm.bin?e=1295445297277&h=50a5fe1407e58226ef61a60a8a38d64a
43875=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-linux-x64.bin?e=1295445300621&h=e928aead541519c22bf9abd9a31890f8
43876=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-solaris-i586.sh?e=1295445101719&h=4c8cd9b7c5549a1ae440e1dfa0b2c68a
43877=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-solaris-sparc.sh?e=1295445105147&h=a46deb6169a5d813661408e15e471ac9
43878=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-solaris-sparcv9.sh?e=1295445108992&h=261ab38219aaee5f0885d7feb00c1b56
43879=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-solaris-x64.sh?e=1295445112989&h=2da48227a0b94bcccd6f9dc6bdc3b06f
43880=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-windows-i586-s.exe?e=1295445117159&h=3f902e861453006c7b448ba883050b3d
43881=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-windows-i586.exe?e=1295445121190&h=a666f498828dc5ec8d168863bff15927
43882=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-windows-ia64.exe?e=1295445124982&h=d7bbc8b701a52847577b8a2cbc8a2814
43883=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/jre-6u23-windows-x64.exe?e=1295445128954&h=e635939bc8275816e9bbecc5799bc8ce
43884=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/JavaSetup6u23-rv.exe?e=1295445132992&h=d2698cb55a192850d6567fc3e0372643
43885=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/JavaSetup6u23-sprev.exe?e=1295445136988&h=dffdc0ba8acc1bb20c68da4e2154d52c
43886=http://dl8-cdn-ll.sun.com/s/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/6u23-b05/JavaSetup6u23.exe?e=1295445140982&h=f4d1879abddf85c06add82411ecb548d
```

Answer (score 7):

Some direct links to old JRE versions (No registration required):

- j2re-1_4_2_05-windows-i586-p.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=9723
- j2re-1_4_2_04-windows-i586-p.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=9567
- j2re-1_4_2_03-windows-i586-p.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=9505
- j2re-1_4_2_02-windows-i586-p.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=9181
- j2re-1_4_2_01-windows-i586-p.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=8939
- jre-6u23-windows-i586-s.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=44457
- jre-7u5-windows-i586.exe - http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=65692

Comment: any links for jdk? where do you get the bundleid?

Answer (score 5):

Historical Java releases are available for download at:

http://java.sun.com/products/archive/